# Excel formula returning unique records except empty cells

Tags: excel

example data in A1:A10:

```
red
[empty]
blue
red
red
[empty]
green
green
[empty]
voilet
```

Where [empty] is blank cell.

Array formula (CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER) in B2 and further down:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$1:$A$10),0))
```

returns following:

```
red
0
blue
green
voilet
```

Can you advise any solution to return only values which are not empty? Simply to get rid of this 'zero'? I could hide 3rd row, but sometimes first empty cell is further down and then 'zero' would be for example 3rd or 4th in the list.

At the end, I would like to get list in column B (or any other column) like this:

```
red
blue
green
voilet
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular formaula (no need for ctrl+shift+enter) in cell B2 and copy down:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$1:$A$10<>"")*(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,$A$1:$A$10)=0),),0))
```